# How to use filedialog to open an excel file and pandas to save/read/write that file

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am very new to Python so apologizing up front for a stupid question. I am building a small application that allows me to first seach for an excel file (with filedialog) from my computer, imports it into the program and then I could do something with it.

So the application has a button "search file" and "save file", but the save_file function doesnt work. It works if I put it inside the open_file function.

Am I going completely to wrong way here? I tried to google like crazy, but didnt find an answer for this

Thanks a lot for your support!

-KV

---

```
""" IMPORT AND SAVE XLSX FILE """


def open_file():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file", filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),("Excel files", ".xls")))
    
    file_entry.insert(END, filename)

def save_file():
    file_data = pd.read_excel(filename)
    print(file_data)

""" UI SETUP """
file_entry = Entry(width=60)
file_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
file_button = Button(text="Select File", width=13, command=open_file)
file_button.grid(row=1, column=2)
file_button = Button(text="Save File", width=13, command=save_file)
file_button.grid(row=1, column=3)
```

Comment: Do you not get any error when you run the function `save_file`? The variable `filename` should not be readable

Comment: yes you defined `filename` inside `open_file` so it's not accessible to `save_file`

Comment: I added "save_file(filename)", I get the error TypeError: save_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'

Answer (score 1):

In `save_file()` the variable `filename` isn't defined. You have to call the function with an argument e. g. `save_file(filename)` or define it inside the function.

Comment: When adding "save_file(filename)", I get the error TypeError: save_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'

Comment: @user14996960: You have to define `filename` before calling the function `save_file(filename)`. Or you can call `save_filename()`and define `filename` inside the function.